# Why there is a difference between Instagram search results via browser and web app?

Tags: python, instagram

When I search Instagram for some tags via browser it send request to server like this one:

https://www.instagram.com/web/search/topsearch/?context=blended&query=#trump&rank_token=0.11476949782296608&include_reel=true

And response JSON contents 100 similar tags.

When I made such request from my web app that based on Flask I received only 55 similar tags. And i can't understand why.

I tried to write headers like browser did, but result is the same.
I found some free services where i can test GET queries, but result was the same.

Here is the Flask function to make a query:

```
def query():
    headers = {'authority': 'www.instagram.com',
            'method': 'GET',
            'scheme': 'https',
            'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
            'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
            'accept-language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
            'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
            'cookie': 'rur=FTW; mid=XEXhXgAEAAFQ0Lg-pAfeVCCnUTzw; mcd=3; csrftoken=IeAstJqVSC7I3TYuKDoCxuGOI5kq4OL3',
            'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
            'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36',
            'x-compress': 'null',
            'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest'
        }
    payload = {'query': request.args.get('text')}
    baseUrl = 'https://www.instagram.com/web/search/topsearch/'

    try:
        response = requests.get(baseUrl, params=payload, headers=headers)
        response.raise_for_status()
    except requests.RequestException:
        return None
```

It works fine, but I expect 100 results, not 55.

If you have some ideas, please tell me.

p.s. Can it be because of session params?

Comment: maybe it's paginating?

Comment: Answer contents 'has_more: false', so i think it isn't pagination

Comment: What is the difference (at HTTP level or maybe even down to TCP) between the requests? If that doesn't explain anything, then it's simply the remote service's program that causes the differences. You'd have to ask the people providing that service then.

Comment: I found the answer. Problem was because of hosting IP. When I started to use proxies I received 100 tags. And it works without any headers.